# identity of vector fields

Tags: analysis, vector-fields

I want to show the following equality:

$\vec{X}\langle\vec{Y},\vec{Z}\rangle = \langle \nabla_{\vec{X}}\vec{Y}, \vec{Z} \rangle +  \langle \vec{Y},\nabla_{\vec{X}} \vec{Z} \rangle$

whereas the RHS of the equation can be expressed as:

$\langle x^j (\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial u^j} + y^i\Gamma^k_{ij})\frac{\partial\vec{F}}{\partial u^k}, \vec{Z} \rangle + \langle \vec{Y}, x^j (\frac{\partial z^k}{\partial u^j} + z^i\Gamma^k_{ij})\frac{\partial\vec{F}}{\partial u^k}\rangle $

which leaves me with a scalar, whereas the LHS gives me the product of a vector field with a scalar. Am I getting this wrong?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: LHS is scalar, as result of the vector field $X$ act on the function $f$ when evaluated at a point.

Comment: That equality you want to prove it is exactly the one that defines a connection "compatible" with the metric. So you cannot prove it in general. It is equivalent to $\partial_k g_{ i j}= g_{l j} \Gamma ^l_{k i} + g_{i l } \Gamma^l_{k j}$.

Comment: I don't understand this, we studied that a vector field maps each point to a vector. How can then $X$ after a function be scalar?

Comment: because the right member is the function $p\mapsto X_p(f) = df_p(X)\in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ where $f $ is the function $p\mapsto \langle Y_p, Z_p\rangle_p $. (identify $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how I can prove the equivalence? I don't know how to compute the left side of the equality.

Comment: replace the $\vec X$ on the LHS by $\sum x_i\partial_{x_i}$